# From a url to an ajax call in history.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web, history.js

I'm writing a small website which has several pages that are very similar. Most of the time, only the content of one div is different. The navigation, header etc stays the same.

So I realized this with a "base" html file, some smaller html-files with only a content-div and javascript code like this (which is triggered by a button click event):

```
$.get("content/text1.html", function(data) {
    $("#content").html(data);
});
```

This works very smooth but the problem was, that the url in the address-bar doesn't change with those kind of requests. So it is not possible for the user to link to certain pages. I know it is possible with #-urls, but i want to have urls like:

> example.com/talks/foo/bar

And not some workaround.

In another Thread, someone gave me a hint to the html5 browser history api (especially [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js)).

What I'm trying to achieve with it:

1. Someone clicks on a button -> an ajax request is triggered and the content of the content-div gets updated -> the url gets updated to something like `example.com/talks/foo/bar`
2. If someone requests `example.com/talks/foo/bar` in his browser directly, the same ajax request and content update as in (1) should be performed

I tried to realize the first one with:

```
$.get("content/text1.html", function(data) {
    $("#content").html(data);
    History.pushState(null, null, "content/text1.html"); 
});
```

But how am I supposed to achieve the second point? With a rewriterule, that redirects everything to the base-html file and some js-logic in it to decode the url and trigger the ajax request?

I have the feeling, that I am a bit on the wrong path..

---

- So is this the way history.js should be used?
- How can i achieve the second bullet point?

Answer (score 0):

To get the initial state in html5 browsers no ajax calls are required. Like you said the url itself gets changed, not the hash so the server should reply to the url with the correct content already loaded.

You should do all your ajax calls and DOM manipulation inside the `statechange` event handler.

So when the user clicks on a link all you do is call `pushState` and handler the DOM changes in the `statechange` event handler. This works because `statechange` is triggered when `pushState` is called.